# how to get current target name with no extension to use on the prerequisite line?

Tags: makefile

I know that `$$@` is used to get the target name on the prerequisite line, but not able to get it to work to find the target name with no extension.

Here is what I mean. I have this

```
foo.pdf : foo.tex
    pdflatex $?
```

But I do not want to duplicate the file name `foo`. I'd like to write like (which does not work)

```
foo.pdf : ${$@:.pdf=.tex)
    latex $?
```

I tried many other variations but nothing worked. The make book I have does not have any example of this.

Any idea how to do the above? Using gmake 3.81 on Linux mint
Or a way to just get the `foo` part of the target so I can use it in the dependency line.

I know I could write this

```
TARGET = foo
${TARGET:=.pdf} : ${TARGET:=.tex}
    latex $?
```

But wanted to see if it is possible to do it differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a pattern rule.

```
# First rule in file, canonically called `all`,
# defines what gets built by default.
all: foo.pdf

# define the rule
%.pdf : %.tex
    pdflatex $<
```

Alternatively, you could use a static pattern rule:

```
foo.pdf: %.pdf : %.tex
    pdflatex $<
```

but I've never had a reason to use this.

Comment: Beat me by a minute :)

Comment: Yes, I know I could do this actually. I have lots of rules like myself in my makefiles. But the whole point of this exercise is for me to learn how to use the `$$@` which is supposed to refer to target on the prerequisites line. I am just looking for the syntax to do as I mentioned and not for alternatives. Is it possible to do directly as in the example I have?

Comment: @Nasser If you're looking to learn when to use `.SECONDEXPANSION:`, the rule is "don't". For any reasonable workflow, it has terrible performance, you're better off using `include` and having a rule generate that file's contents.